# A torus quotient an equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

A torus is $S^1\times S^1=\{(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})|x,y\in \Bbb R\}$, define an equivalence relation $(w,z) \sim (iw,iz)$. I want to know $S^1\times S^1/\sim$.

I try to rewrite it in $\Bbb R^2$, $(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})=(x,y)$,$(w,z) \sim (iw,iz)$ is $(x,y) \sim (x+1/4,y+1/4)$, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The last claim is very unclear (and as stated, false). You can't put an equality between two nonequal things such as $e^{it}$ and $t$,

Comment: Maybe this helps. As you know, the torus can be seen as the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where opposite sides are identified (in the same direction). If $(x,y)\sim (x+1/4,y+1/4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as you said, then you can think about what happens to your unit square and if you recognise this space.

Comment: Your “definition “ is not one. Define what you really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a good start (+1).  The following picture should help now:

[image]

On the left we have a standard representation of the unit square with opposite edges identified.  The equivalence relation generated by $\sim$ will take any point in the square to one (at least) in the bottom quarter.  Thus we can model the quotient of the torus as a quotient of the bottom rectangle.

We may break off the left hand triangle from the bottom rectangle, and glue along the vertical identification.  We must identify the diagonal edges to record where we made this break.

The only points in the resulting trapezium which are equivalent under $\sim$ are corresponding points on the top and bottom edges.

The end result is just another torus.

Comment: I don't see how you're taking into account the horizontal identification with shift $1/4$. What is the relevance of the line $y=x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin. It Is a diagonal shift of $(1/4,1/4)$ - see second paragraph of question.